# Email signup reporting?

Tags: contacts, email, reports

Is there a way to generate a monthly report on new email signups? We just want to track new users that sign up via our website platform. Thanks in advance!

Comment: for your email sign up, are your contacts being added to a Group?

Answer (score 3):

In the Advanced Search, under the Change Log section, you can specify a search criteria based on the date of creation of the contact. You could specify "Previous Calendar Month", and then click search, choose the "All xyz records" radio option and then select "Group - create smart group", calling it maybe "New Contacts, Last Month".

Then you can use that group as a filter with your favourite contact report (probably you want the "Constituent Summary") and voila, a report of last month's new contacts.

If you only want those that are coming in via a particular signup, then you'd need to add in additional filters (e.g. if it's using a profile, you can configure the profile to add new signups into a group).

Answer (score 2):

Welcome Rachel! As Pete's question suggests, the answer to your question depends on how your signup was set up. In all likelihood,su you're adding people to a group.  Do you know how to install extensions?  My [Subscription History extension](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/org.cpehn.subscriptionhistory) is one good choice.  If you have an up-to-date version of CiviCRM, you can also use SearchKit.